# Fire event after SizeChanged in WinRT / Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-8, size

I've got a `Grid` that resizes when the app is snapped. It has to update an animation based on the new `ActualWidth` of an element. However, when I tie this function to the `SizeChanged` event, it seems to fire before the snapped view is redrawn, and calculates the previous `ActualWidth`.

How do I ensure that my function runs AFTER the app is redrawn post-snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LayoutUpdated` event to run any code when the layout updates. Use a bool set to true on `SizeChanged` and then set to false again before you do anything to make sure you don't cause a loop!